# SoundPool loading failing

Tags: android, soundpool

This is my first Android app. Java is new to me.

I am trying to use SoundPool but the sound file is not getting loaded. In the `Button.setOnClickListener` method in a fragment, trying to play a sound strip, but it is not working.

I did some research on this issue by browsing internet including this website. Could not get correct reasons for failure and a fix.

My code is as follows:

```
public class LauncherFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentLauncherBinding binding;

    SoundPool soundPool;
    int launcher ;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentLauncherBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes
                    audioAttributes
                    = new AudioAttributes
                    .Builder()
                    .setUsage(
                            AudioAttributes
                                    .USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(
                            AudioAttributes
                                    .CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build();
            soundPool
                    = new SoundPool
                    .Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(3)
                    .setAudioAttributes(
                            audioAttributes)
                    .build();
        }
        else {
            soundPool
                    = new SoundPool(
                    3,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    0);
        }


        try {
            launcher
                    = soundPool
                    .load(
                            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.soundbite_mpthree,
                            1);
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(LauncherFragment.this.getContext(), "Load failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.launcherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                soundPool.play(
                        launcher, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                soundPool.autoPause();

                NavHostFragment.findNavController(LauncherFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_LauncherFragment_to_ActionFragment);
            }
        });
    }
```

During debugging, I found the value of `launcher` to be 1 and debugger console messaged "E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample: (null)".

Please let me know where my code is wrong and fix for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed audioAttributes `.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION` to '.USAGE_MEDIA`. Then used mp3 file of size less than 40KB instead of ogg file. When I run debugger, soundPool works but actual run it wont. Is it because the next code statement is navigating to another fragment. How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was making following changes to the code.

1. Changing audioAttributes from `.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION to '.USAGE_MEDIA`.
2. Using short mp3 file of size less than 40 KB instead of ogg file
3. using `handler.post(new Runnable(){  //code to play sound handler.postDelayed(); to introduce some delay for soundpool to complete its job });`
   I do not know how solution 1 and 2 resolved loading sound file. But it worked.